# Running time of a function of n

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Provide a tight Θ bound on the running time of the function of n.

```
for a=1 to n
   for b=1 to lg(n)
      for c = 1 to 23
         x = 2x
```

My thinking in solving this problem was "x=2x" is a constant so it would be only occur 23 times. I believe this will just cancel out to be some constant?

Currently my answer is $\sum_{a=1}^n \sum_{b=1}^{\lg(n)} \sum_{c=1}^{23} (x=2x)$

Can someone provide me with some guidance for this algorithm analysis question and in simplifying? (I am currently trying to learn latex to post it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$x=2x$" has nothing to do in your running-time -- it is something the function *does*, and doesn't say how long it takes to do it.

If we suppose that multiplication and assignments both take constant time, each execution of `x=2x` will take some fixed time $t_0$. So you need to figure out how many times that is executed. $23$ is not the answer here -- the doubling happens 23 times *each time* the body of the `b` loop runs!

If you don't worry about fancy notation for the moment, how would you compute the number of executions of `x=2x` for some concrete value of $n$ -- for example, $n=64$?

Comment: I would have sum of n=1 to 64 Θ(1). is that correct?

Comment: @Masterminder: No. Let me repeat: _Don't worry about fancy notation for now_. It looks like sum notation confuses you, and you don't actually need it here. Imagine you just had pencil and paper and perhaps a calculator -- what would you do to find _how many times_ `x=2x` executes, as a concrete number?

Comment: It does slightly. I would say it executes 64 times.

Comment: @Masterminder: The _outer_ loop executes 64 times. But surely you're not thinking that there's only one execution of `x=2x` each time the _outer_ loop executes once? 64 is probably too high to do experiments, but try setting `n` to 4 instead and then run the code with `print "hello"` instead of `x=2x`. I assure you, you will get more than 4 hellos.

Comment: If you have i=0, i<4,i++, you will get four of them. Unless you are thinking of something else?

Comment: @Masterminder: Have you _actually tried_ running the program? For n=4 you ought to get 184 hellos.

Comment: How would I ever get 184 hellos? I ran a loop with what I wrote in my previous comment

Comment: You changed the loop structure, which is the important feature. When loops are nested, the inner block runs the product of the counts

Comment: @Masterminder: The program I asked you to run was the one you're trying to find the running time of (except with a debug trace put in so you can see how many times the `x=2x` executes), not a completely different one that has only one of the three nested loop in the program you're interested in.

Comment: Okay I ran it with all of them and seem to get that amount. Can you continue with your solution?

Comment: @Masterminder: The next part is for you to _understand what the program does_, and figure out how you could have predicted it would execute 184 times.

Comment: Yes I know. But I am looking for how to simplify this because I would not have posted if I was stuck. Can you help a bit more in regards to the simplification involved?

Comment: @Masterminder: No. As I said, **YOU NEED TO UNDERSTAND WHAT THE PROGRAM DOES**. Once you do that, writing down the solution will be blindingly obvious to you. Before you understand what the program does, being shown the solution as the result of a series of mindless manipulations that you have no understanding of, will not help you at all.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have set n=4 and then ran the three for loops and got 184. I am trying really hard to understand this. If we set n=4 I know the first loop executes 23 times, the second loop will only execute log(n) times and the third will execute n times. So we have n*log(n)*23 and I know this gives you 184. So it looks like to me the runtime is nlog(n). and it should be some of i=1 to nlog(n)  Θ(1) ???

Comment: @Masterminder: $n\log n$ is correct. Once you have found that answer, there is no point in trying to express that as a summation.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my suggested guidelines:

If there is a for loop that repeats $n$ times, this is a linear complexity $Θ(n)$ as it will occur that many times.

If there is a for loop that repeats $log(n)$ times, this is logarithmic complexity $Θ(log(n))$ for the same reason.

If a loop repeats a constant number of times, then this is $Θ(1)$ complexity as it doesn't matter what size $n$ is.

As loops are within loops, this should be multiplied together as each is repeating for the next in the chain.

As an example, you could probably do a big-O of $O(n log(n))$ to give the upper bound as half of what you have to prove here.  That would be my suggestions for a starting point.

[Sorting](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10991/complexities-of-basic-operations-of-searching-and-sorting-algorithms) would be a well studied problem if you want an example to help you here.

Comment: it looks like to me that it is n*log(n)*23 the runtime? or further simplified sum of i=1 to nlog(n)  Θ(1). Is that correct?

Comment: No, the 23 is a constant that can be removed but the n log n doesn't get factored out.